# Calculate percentage of String values in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table, where questions have been answered either pass or fail.

I just need an SQL query to find the percentage of Fails for question 1 out of the total number of questions asked.

I'm trying this, but this is coming up with a Syntax error -

```
$CA001 = "COUNT(CA001Result WHERE CA001Result = "Fail") / COUNT(CA001Result)) From Datable";
```

As I said, total noob, it's MYSQL btw.

I no need to isolate the % results for Product, I've got this so far, and have tried GROUP by Product but that didn't work, any ideas?

```
$CA001 = "( SELECT ROUND(100 *  (SELECT count(CA001Result ) from Data_Table where (CA001Result='Fail' AND Product='$product' AND Area='$Area'))/count(CA001Result),2) from Data_Table) AS 'CA001 %'";
```

Looking at it again I need to insert a WHERE Product = 'Product' somewhere like where I have it below, however don't quite understand where to put it as the below doesn't work:

$`CA001 = "( SELECT ROUND(100 *  (SELECT count(CA001Result ) from Data_Table where (CA001Result='Fail' AND Product='$product' AND Area='$Area'))/count(CA001Result WHERE Product = '$product'),2) from Data_Table) AS 'CA001 %'";`

Comment: Which SQL? MySQL, SQL Server or other?

Comment: Please give  query details you have tried or even the table schema ....

Comment: added what is probably some embarrassing attempt :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose this is your table:

```
ID     Answer
-------------
 1  ,  'pass'
 2  ,  'pass'
 3  ,  'fail'
 4  ,  'fail'
 5  ,  'fail'
 6 ,   'fail'
```

So you need to use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT 100 * 
(SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM t WHERE answer='fail')/COUNT(answer)
AS Fail_percent FROM t;
```

Or you can use `COUNT` with `CASE` like this:

```
SELECT 100 * 
COUNT(CASE WHEN answer = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(answer)
AS Fail_percent FROM t;
```

Or you can use `SUM` with `CASE` like this:

```
SELECT 100 * 
SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(answer)
AS Fail_percent FROM t;
```

Or you can use `SUM` without using `CASE` (Only for MySQL) like this:

```
SELECT 100 * 
SUM(answer = 'fail')/COUNT(answer)
AS Fail_percent FROM t;
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df68a/24)

Comment: Thanks for these mate, further to this I'm trying to isolate these %'s by a 3rd column 'Product' so that it shows for instance the % of Product A questions answered Pass or Fail.  I've edited my above question to show what I've got so far, I tried, GROUP By Product but that didn't work. Can you offer any advice?

Comment: Need to Elaborate on the above a bit by narrowing it down based on area, and product - details here if you can help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164092/calculating-using-variables-in-mysql-query